# Group a spark dataframe by a starting event to an ending event

Tags: data-cleaning, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a series of events (with datetime) such as:

failed, failed, passed, failed, passed, passed

I want to retrieve the time from when it first "failed" to when it first "passed," resetting every time it fails again, as I want to measure the recovery time.

I only succeeded doing this with a for loop, as when I `groupBy` the event with `min` in the date I lost the order of events, as I want to group by failed-passed pairs.

Ultimately I want to measure the average recovery time of this test.

Example data:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from datetime import datetime

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 11, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 13, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 14, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 15, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 16, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 17, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 18, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 19, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 0))
])

df.show()

+------+-------------------+
| event|               date|
+------+-------------------+
|failed|2021-08-11 00:00:00|
|failed|2021-08-12 00:00:00|
|passed|2021-08-13 00:00:00|
|failed|2021-08-14 00:00:00|
|failed|2021-08-15 00:00:00|
|passed|2021-08-16 00:00:00|
|passed|2021-08-17 00:00:00|
|passed|2021-08-18 00:00:00|
|failed|2021-08-19 00:00:00|
|passed|2021-08-20 00:00:00|
+------+-------------------+
```

expected result:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(failed=datetime(2021, 8, 11, 0, 0), recovered=datetime(2021, 8, 13, 0, 0)),
  Row(failed=datetime(2021, 8, 14, 0, 0), recovered=datetime(2021, 8, 16, 0, 0)),
  Row(failed=datetime(2021, 8, 19, 0, 0), recovered=datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 0)),
])

df.show()

+-------------------+-------------------+
|             failed|          recovered|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2021-08-11 00:00:00|2021-08-13 00:00:00|
|2021-08-14 00:00:00|2021-08-16 00:00:00|
|2021-08-19 00:00:00|2021-08-20 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

there may be better ways to do this, but this seems to work

1. filter out repeated events by comparing the lag with and without partitioning
2. compute the lead without partitioning
3. filter failed events

````
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 11, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 13, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 14, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 15, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 16, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 17, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 18, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="failed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 19, 0, 0)),
  Row(event="passed", date=datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 0))
])

w = Window.partitionBy("event").orderBy("date")
w_wo_key = Window.orderBy("date")

(
df
 .withColumn("lag_date", F.lag("date", 1, None).over(w))
 .withColumn("lag_wo_key", F.lag("date",1,None).over(w_wo_key))
 .filter((F.col("lag_date").isNull()) | (F.col("lag_date") != F.col("lag_wo_key")))
 .withColumn("recovered", F.lead("date",1,None).over(w_wo_key))
 .filter(F.col("event") == 'failed')
 .select(
   F.col("date").alias("failed"),
   F.col("recovered"))
).show()

""" Returns
+-------------------+-------------------+                                       
|             failed|          recovered|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2021-08-11 00:00:00|2021-08-13 00:00:00|
|2021-08-14 00:00:00|2021-08-16 00:00:00|
|2021-08-19 00:00:00|2021-08-20 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
"""

```
````